# Is there anyway of retrieving random url parameter in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I use laravel notifiable to send an email to a specific user everytime i make a new invoice.

With this email i send an url with the link to the invoice like this:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $url = url('/invoices/'.$this->id.'/edit');

    return (new MailMessage)
    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
    ->action('Notification Action', url($url))
    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

Output url = customer/invoices/6c081f60-d25a-4798-bf6e-bcc4924b1e53/edit

My controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $invoice = InvoicesData::where('invoice_id', $id)->first();

    return view('customer.invoices.edit', compact('invoice'));


}
```

How do i retrieve the 'id' parameter from the url in my controller function?

Should i strip my url or is there another option?

Like laravel uses in web.php

```
Route::resource('customer/invoices', 'CustomerInvoiceController', ['names' 
=> [

    'index' => 'customer.invoices.index',
    'store' => 'customer.invoices.store',
    'edit' => 'customer.invoices.edit',

]]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What ? you already retrieve it no ? it's only the `$id` variable you want to use ?

Comment: Yes, i only want the id variable to have the value of the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the full url then the random id is the third segment`customer/invoices/6c081f60-d25a-4798-bf6e-bcc4924b1e53/edit`.   In Laravel you can do...

```
$id = $request->segment(3);
```

Or

```
$id = Request::segment(3);
```

Comment: Its not reliable when route changes but it worked, thanks!

Comment: Does that random string of characters always stay the same length? (i.e. 36 characters)  You could  use `$request->segments()` to get all segments in an array, and then search the array for a string with length = 36 using `strlen()` to get your id.